# What is wrong with Plant

Tags: plant-care, protection

First i dont know the name of this Plant. I bought it two months ago. It was growing very well But two weeks ago it started giving signs something is wrong. So i took out the Plant from Planter there were roots going around possibly Root Bound. So i brought new Planter and added peat moss + Perlite combination. But this is still happening. This Plant seems to be dying and i have no idea whats wrong with it.

There is no any kind of infestation. I have already pruned it 2/3 but problem still exist

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is Ficus benjamina en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus_benjamina. Hates being moved and disturbed. Hates drafts and temperature changes. Does well when allowed to be out of doors on a covered porch for the summer. It is able to make enough food for itself to last the winter.

This looks like too much water. Change that soil. Open up the root system as you plant it in the SAME pot in sterilized potting soil. Just the soil above a drainage hole the bottom of the pot lifted above the surface using pot feet or pieces of broken tile. Osmocote 14-14-14 at HALF what the directions tell you to use. Nothing else added.  Constant and quite environment.  When healthy, put out on a covered! porch for the summer months.  Do not take chances with possible freezes.

Learn how a potted plant feels in weight when watered properly.  When that pot and soil and plant feels OBVIOUSLY lighter then water deeply again and not before.  Roots need O2 or they will start anaerobic decomposition (rot) and your plant will die. If all the pore spaces in the medium are compacted there is no air, no O2 for the roots.

When you repot, and this needs to be done SOON, gently, examine the roots, knock off any wet soil, cut off brown or mushy roots.  Spread the roots gently over a pile of the soil then add more soil, FIRM that soil as you add soil and the surface of the soil should be 1" below the rim for proper watering.  Don't allow the bottom of the pot to sit in any water for any length of time and those tile pieces really add to the drainage lifting the bottom of the pot off the surface disrupting the surface tension of water.  No rocks or gravel beneath the soil and above the drain hole.  None.

What have your maintenance practices been? This looks like too much water. Are you allowing the soil to dry out in between waterings...? Not completely dry but if you are watering everyday you are watering too much. Your soil sounds iffy. Plants in pots need sterilized planting medium or Potting Soil. Never garden soil. The bag of potting soil (not top soil or compost) should say sterilized potting medium.  You'll find that there is very little soil if any in potting soil.  Absolutely no frills should be added to the potting soil: such as water holding gimmicks or fertilizer. You need to know how much fertilizer has been added to the entire equation.  It is best to keep it simple.  OSMOCOTE 14-14-14 ext. release.

How much light does this guy get? That shadow of your plant on the wall should be in crisp contrast at least 4 hours per day.

Ask us about any question concerning humans and our oh so artificial gardens. I would like to hear that you get the chance to have success.  Get bucked off you get back on...without a whimper.

Comment: It is a Ficus but not F. benjamina. The leaves would be thinner and the tip would be pointier.  However your advice is still good!

Comment: Thanks Kev.  I thought so as well but the most common ficus people purchase is Benjamina.  Depending on the growing conditions those leaves can become more oval and thinner.  Or thicker yet a bit thinner with the tip correct.

Comment: Sorry  for late reply guys , but just to update plant died . I pruned it back and moved to smaller container but alas didnt survived

Comment: Omi, when you decide to get another plant, any plant, please talk it over with us so that this doesn't happen ever again. What a bummer!  Don't forget to ask for help.  Even the tiniest thing to you could be a big deal for the plant and we most certainly can guide you!

Comment: will do so @stormy, I did by Ficus benjamina instead of the one above, it was also root bounded but this time i only went a slightly bigger size instead much much bigger than the root bowl . New plant is doing well

Comment: Yay.  You've learned from your bad experience and are moving on.  Others would have given up on plants completely.  Keep in touch!